# Awesomium.NET Flash Player

Tags: wpf, flash, awesomium

I'm tring to use Flash Player into WPF application using Awesomium.. I've downloaded and installed the 1.7.2 SDK..

In my WPF app i can now use the `Awesomium.NET` `WebBrowser` control, but Flash Player is not working. I've did a quick check on YouTube and videos are loaded using HTML5

I've searched multiple times on google and also on the official website, but there is not much documentation available, and for some users Flash Player is working.

Is there any option to set up? Or i need to specify a Plugin Path?

I don't know if Awesomium is getting the Flash from IE/Chrome/Firefox already installed Browser.. But i do have them all, with Flash plugin Installed.

Currently i do not have much code, only the XAML Awesomium Control, added from VS2012 ToolBox

PS: In my application i only need to open a static SWF with parameters, and a HTML5+JS page so if there is something better for that, i apreciate also alternatives, except the WPF `WebControl` since it use IE Engine and the HTML5 page i'm loading into it only support IE 10 +

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you use correct control? WebControl it is Awesomium control, WebBrowser it's WPF control. If it's correct try create folder 'plugins' in bin folder and put there npswf32_11_8_800_94.dll

Comment: I'm using the Awesomium Control (Red Background with Logo).. Already tried putting the Flash dll but no changes.